# How to get a part of a string with a regular expression in a /bin/sh script

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need to extract the part of a string in a shell script. The original string is pretty complicated, so I really need a regular expression to select the right part of the original string - justing removing a prefix and suffix won't work. Also, the regular expression needs to check the context of the string I want to extract, so I e.g. need a regular expression `a\([^b]*\)b` to extract `123` from `12a123b23`.

The shell script needs to be portable, so I cannot make use of the Bash constructs `[[` and `BASH_REMATCH`.

I want the script to be robust, so when the regular expression does not match, the script should notice this e.g. through a non-zero exit code of the command to be used.

What is a good way to do this?

---

I've tried various tools, but none of them fully solved the problem:

- `expr match "$original" ".*$regex.*"` works except for the error case. With this command, I don't know how to detect if the regex did not match. Also, expr seems to take the extracted string to determine its exit code - so when I happened to extract `00`, expr had an exit code of 1. So I would need to generally ignore the exit code with `expr match "$original" ".*$regex.*" || true`
- `echo "$original" | sed "s/.*$regex.*/\\1/"` also works except for the error case. To handle this case, I'd need to test if I got back the original string, which is also quite unelegant.

So, isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: have you tried `echo $original | grep -o $regex` I think that does exactly that, -o prints only the part of the regex that matches.

Comment: Can you provide some samples of input string and your expected matches?

Comment: @MikeH-R, `grep -o` is a GNUism, not a portable POSIX-specified option.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I didn't know that, is there a portable version of this? I just googled about and couldn't find one.

Comment: @MikeH-R, not for `grep`, no. You could do something portable with awk or sed.

Comment: sed will not return another RC than 0 (unless input or regex is bad) so no test from this. You could assume a predefine content like '--Not-FoUnd--' and test it if you are sur this content could not occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `-n` option of `sed` to suppress output of all input lines and add the `p` option to the substitute command, like this:

```
echo "$original" | sed -n -e "s/.*$regex.*/\1/p"
```

If the regular expression matches, the matched group is printed as before. But now if the regular expression does not match, nothing is printed and you will need to test only for the empty string.

Comment: to be portable (you still need to define the level of portability like between OS or system, shell ...) add the `-e` before your action string. Still it does not reply to request about failing to found the pattern return a RC > 0

Comment: Right, added -e. About the return value: it is now only a test if the result is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

How about `grep -o` the only possible problem is portability, otherwise it satisfies all requirements:

```
➜  echo "hello and other things" | grep -o hello
hello
➜  echo $?
0
➜  echo "hello and other things" | grep -o nothello
➜  echo $?
1
```

One of the best things is that since it's grep you can pick what regex's you want whether BRE, ERE or Perl.

Comment: ...well, for POSIX grep, you get BRE or ERE only. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of `grep -o`. Unfortunately, I only need group 1 from the regular expression. It's unfortunately not possible to detect the part I want to extract only from its content. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: I'm sure you could with Perl regexes, just have everything before the match be a lookbehind `(?<=like_this)` and everything after be a lookahead `(?=like_this)` but as mentioned by @CharlesDuffy that is not available for POSIX grep.

Answer (score 0):

if egrep is available (pretty much all time)

```
egrep 'YourPattern' YourFile
```

or

```
egrep "${YourPattern}" YourFile
```

if only grep is available

```
grep -e 'YourPattern' YourFile
```

you check with a classical `[ $? -eq 0 ]` for the status of the command (also take into account bad YourFile access)

for the content itself, extract with sed or awk (for portability issue) (after the failure test)

```
Content="$( sed -n -e "s/.*\(${YourPattern}\).*/\1/p;q" )"
```